# Burninate [sample] and [samples] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

We've gotten rid of [sample-code](/questions/tagged/sample-code) and we're <strike>nearly</strike> done with [code-sample](/questions/tagged/code-sample). I just noticed two others which are along  a similar vein: [sample](/questions/tagged/sample) and [samples](/questions/tagged/samples). The above four tags seem to generally be concerned with the same bad questions, and they don't seem to be at all useful. This would make them ideal for burnination.

Thoughts?

Comment: The [tag:sample] tag is used in conjunction with the [tag:r] tag in the context of "take a sample of some set" in the process of data/statistical analysis. Not sure that justifies a whole tag, but it's a use that has nothing to do with the meaning of [tag:sample-code].

Comment: I would suggest that the [tag:sample] tag is too generic for that purpose - maybe [tag:sample-set] or something similar should be applied to those questions?

Comment: Mmmm...not really. The problem is that there is a specific function in R for this purpose called `sample`.

Comment: I've seen this before elsewhere, but I forget where: Tags designated for one specific command in a language should not be created (with few exceptions for common ones like `select`, but as it stands, [tag:sample] doesn't even have a tag wiki).

Comment: Well, [tag:sampling] seems like a better replacement to me, but that's already taken with a pretty specific meaning.

Comment: Do you think it would be ok to expand the tag wiki for [tag:sampling] and use that for the ~40 questions in R that currently have [tag:sample]?

Comment: @joran No, I think tags should have one meaning only

Comment: Ok, I guess we're stuck with [tag:random-sample] then. Now I need to figure out what to do with [tag:bootstrap]. Man, tags are such a mess.

Comment: @joran Yes, they certainly are. I've got a list of around 70 now that need cleaning

Answer (score 2):

They certainly aren't used for the same reasons at all...

With that:

[image]